# Issue setting folder path in Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have an image gallery made in Tkinter that lets you cycle through images. I am trying to set a path to a folder where the images can be stored. When there is no path set the code runs just fine because the images and script are saved in the same place (Pycharm). However, when a path is set this error is thrown `raise ValueError(f"bad mode {repr(mode)}")` specifically on this line of code `image = PIL.Image.open(mpath, image_list[current], 'r')` . Iv referenced other posts saying that there maybe an interference with the `.open()` from the imported PIL module but cant seem to figure it out. Iv tried changing mode from `r` to `rb` but still get the same error.  Any recommendations?

```
import PIL.Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

# path to image folder
mpath = "C:/Users/Me/Demo/DemoProject/Pics"

# List of images
image_list = ['2022-07-11_14-35-44.png', '2022-07-11_14-34-08.png']

current = 0

# Cycle through Image List
def move(delta):
    global current, image_list, mpath
    if not (0 <= current + delta < len(image_list)):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('End', 'No more image.')
        return
    current += delta
    image = PIL.Image.open(mpath, image_list[current], 'r')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    fileName = image_list[current]
    print(fileName)

    # Get values from image
    def getvalues():
        img = fileName
        Dimage = PIL.Image.open(mpath, img, 'r')

        data = ''
        imgdata = iter(Dimage.getdata())

        while (True):
            pixels = [value for value in imgdata.__next__()[:3] +
                      imgdata.__next__()[:3] +
                      imgdata.__next__()[:3]]

            # string of binary data
            binstr = ''

            for i in pixels[:8]:
                if (i % 2 == 0):
                    binstr += '0'
               else:
                    binstr += '1'

            data += chr(int(binstr, 2))
            if (pixels[-1] % 2 != 0):
                return data
    print(getvalues())

    label['text'] = (str("Decoded Pic : ")+ getvalues())
    label['image'] = photo
    label.photo = photo

mRoot = tkinter.Tk()

label = tkinter.Label(mRoot, compound=tkinter.TOP)
label.pack()

frame = tkinter.Frame(mRoot)
frame.pack()

tkinter.Button(frame, text='Previous picture', command=lambda: 
move(-1)).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
tkinter.Button(frame, text='Next picture', command=lambda: move(+1)).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=mRoot.quit).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

move(0)

mRoot.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is that the entire error or is there a dirtier stacktrace? If yes, you might want to post that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing multiple params to `Image`.

```
image = PIL.Image.open(mpath + '/' + image_list[current], 'r')
```

Concatenate the folder path and image name instead of passing them as separate params.

You can also do something like,

```
image = PIL.Image.open(os.path.join(mpath, image_list[current]), 'r')
```

Ofcourse, letting python handle paths is a much better idea.

Comment: Thank you this worked! The only issue now is the returned vales from the `getvalues()` function are a bit scrambled. Probably because I'm passing multiple params to `img` like my issue above.

Comment: `Dimage = PIL.Image.open(mpath, img, 'r')` this line also needs to change.

Comment: Tried switching it to `Dimage =PIL.Image.open(mpath + '/' + img, 'r')` but values are still being scrambled

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows, you may need to escape your /'s in the given path or use r"directory/here/etc" to tell python it's a raw string and to ignore escape chars.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).